# All distinct k-permutations of length n, with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Given $n$ elements and an integer $k > 0~(k \leq n)$, find the number of **all distinct** strings of length $n$, formed by any $k$-out-of-$n$ distinct symbols (i.e., $k$-permutations of length $n)$. Each symbol is equally likely to be picked and there are no restrictions on the number of repetitions for each symbol.

**As a related problem**, let the exact number of repetitions, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$, for each of the $k$ symbols be given, such that $x_1$ gives the exact number of repetitions for the first symbol picked (which can be any of the $n$ symbols). In general, $x_i$ gives the exact number of repetitions for $i^{th}$ selected element. Hence, $x_i$ gives only the (exact) count of duplicates and it says nothing about the symbols picked. In such scenario, the answer should be given by:

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{P_{n,k}\cdot k^{n-k}}{|x_1|\cdot |x_2| \cdot \dots \cdot |x_k|}
\end{equation}

**But, the main problem in consideration** does not give the count of the number of duplicates. Also, as mentioned earlier, the $k$ symbols are not fixed, and each symbol is equally likely to be picked. Thus, I am trying to figure out a formula, which given the value of $n$ and $k$, computes **all distinct** $k$-permutations of length $n$, without any restriction on the repetitions/duplicates or the selection.

*How I got to the aforementioned formula:* First, we select $k$ out of $n$ elements. As the order matters, the number of ways to do this is given by $P_{n,k}$. For the rest of the $n-k$ empty spots, the selection is done from the same set of $k$ symbols. Hence, $k^{n-k}$ ways to do so! Finally, as we know the exact number of repetitions for each of the $k$ symbols, we use that information to avoid overcounting. I included the related problem and the equation/formula to improve the clarity on the main problem and the goal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ... but what is the question?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to count all strings of length $n$ with $k$ symbols, or do you first fix the repetition of each symbol?

Comment: @Momo The problem is to derive a formula that given $n$ and $k$, computes the number of distinct $k$-permutations of length $n$, without any restrictions on the repetitions allowed for each element. The formula (which might be incorrect!) I derived assumes that we know the number of duplicates allowed per element.

Comment: @GuidoA. There should be no restriction on the number of repetitions allowed. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question. Hopefully it's less ambiguous now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an amount of repetitions for each symbol $r_i \geq 1$, for each $i \in [k]$. Since we want our permutations to have *exactly* $k$ symbols, $r_1 + \dots+ r_k = n$. Now, given this information, how many permutations can we form? First off, we can fix $r_1$ of the $n$ elements, and place the first symbol (this way, we do not overcount swapping the order of this places). For the remaning $n - r_1$, we again pick $r_2$ of them to place the second symbol; and so on. That is, we have the following amount of possibilities:

$$
{n \choose r_1}{n-r_1 \choose r_2}\cdots{n - r_1 - \dots r_{k-2} \choose r_{k-1}} = {n \choose r_1, \dots r_k}
$$

so the total amount of possibilities is:

$$
\sum\limits_{r_1 + \dots + r_k = n \\ \quad r_i \geq 1 \ (\forall i)}{n \choose r_1, \dots r_k} 
$$

Perhaps this can be made more explicit by noting that

$$
\sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_k = n}{n \choose r_1, \dots r_k} = \sum_{r_1 + \dots + r_k = n}{n \choose r_1, \dots r_k}1^{r_1}\cdots1^{r_k} = (1 + \dots + 1)^n = k^n
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are issues with it. Let me explain:


1. The number of repetitions allowed for the elements are not fixed as we're considering all distinct $k$-permutations of length $n$. Hence, if $r_i$ represents the number of repetitions allowed for element $i$, then it may hold that: $r_1 + r_2 + \dots + r_k \gg n$.


2. Also, all $n$ elements are equally likely to be picked. Hence, it's possible that $k-1$ elements are picked only once and the $k^{th}$ element occupies $n-k+1$ spots.

Comment: Your strings have length $n$, how can $r_1 + \dots + r_k > n$? Also, I'm fixing the amount of repetitions and then summing to count them all. Perhaps I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: My bad!! You're correct. It seems like it's me who didn't understand the problem properly. Thanks!

Comment: I have a counter example for $k^n$ as a solution. Let $S = \{0,1,2\}$ be a set of $n=3$ elements. For $k=2$, the distinct $2$-permutations of length $3$ are: 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 002, 020, 022, 200, 202, 220, 112, 121, 122, 211, 212, 221. Hence, 18 distinct strings of length $3$ are formed by $2$-out-of-$3$ symbols. But, $k^n = 8$.

Comment: I'm never said that $k^n$ was the solution, note that in the last sum I dropped one of the conditions. I'm only pointing out that this fact *may* help to get a more amenable closed form, since indexing by all $r_1 + \dots r_k = 1$ with $r_i \geq 1 \ (\forall i)$ is not very easy to handle.

Comment: Correct, but the goal is to get to a closed-form expression for any given $n$ and $k$ values. I have edited the question. Please see if it makes more sense now, especially in the light of the example I gave earlier. Thanks for your time! I really appreciate it!